# How to populate nested attribute with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

With the `user` being:

```
user: {
  email: 'name@yahoo.com',
  doc: {
    models: [ 5f41c02673d374386e1f9b07 ],
    _id: 5f41c02773d374386e1f9b08,
    doc_name: 'doc_name',
  },
}
```

I want to populate the `user.doc.models`

I am trying:

```
User.findOne({"email": 'name@yahoo.com'})
  .populate({ 
     path: 'doc',
     model: 'Doc',
     populate: {
       path: 'doc.models',
       model: 'Model'
     } 
  })
```

But it only returns the `models` ids:

```
_user: {
  _id: 5f41c02773d374386e1f9b09,
  email: 'name@yahoo.com',
  doc: {
    models: [ 5f41c02673d374386e1f9b07 ],
    _id: 5f41c02773d374386e1f9b08,
    doc_name: 'doc_name',
    __v: 0
  },
  __v: 0
}
```

How to populate the `User.doc.models`?

Comment: Try this - `User.findOne({ email: 'name@yahoo.com' })
.populate({
  path: 'user.doc.models',
  model: 'Model'
});`

Comment: It returns this: ```{
  email: 'name@yahoo.com',
  doc: 5f41d19fc981683ce4302798,
}```

Comment: Can you please show the code for your user and document models?